# Why is the Ctrl+Shift+Z hotkey opening the ExtraPuTTY Examples folder?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Whenever I press Control + Shift + Z (ctrl+shift+z) to redo in an application, Windows Explorer opens up with the ExtraPuTTY Examples folder:

*C:\Program Files\ExtraPuTTY\Bin\Examples*

I figured out why, so I'm posting the answer for others with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you install ExtraPuTTY, it creates a shortcut in the start menu to the *Examples* folder, and in the shortcut properties it defines the hotkey *Control+Shift+Z* to run/launch it.

**To solve this issue**, you can go to:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ExtraPuTTY\Examples
```

(for example, it will look like this, with "charles" replaced with your windows username):

```
C:\Users\charles\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ExtraPuTTY\Examples
```

Then right-click on the *Examples* shortcut in that folder
Click **Properties**
Click inside the **Shortcut Key** box.
Press **Backspace** (or Delete) to clear the shortcut.
Click **OK**.

**To avoid this issue**:

When you're installing ExtraPuTTY, you can deselect the option to install Examples.

---

*Tested with both the snapshot version of ExtraPuTTY (ExtraPuTTY-0.30-2016-04-04-installer), and the release candidate version (ExtraPuTTY-0.29-RC2-installer).*

*I'm submitting this as an official bug as well, but it looks like development has been stalled for a few years. Thus I'm posting the info here for more general visibility.*